# Wordpress common / shared installation

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wordpress

I need to create a common installtion of Wordpress which I can then use accross a number of domains.

I have looked into Wordpress Multisite but I can't want to point all the domains to the same hosting account each domain will need to have it's own hosting domain.

To clarify I need to do the following:

- Install a wordpress codebase
- Use this codebase for any domain of the server without pointing the domain at that hosting account
- Be able to update the Wordpress core & plugins only once

Is this possible??

Hosting specs - UNIX hosting, PHP 5+, MYSQL

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone but it looks like the only way I can achieve this on the server is going to open up to many issues with security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can acheive this requirement:

> Use this codebase for any domain of the server without pointing the domain at that hosting account

Without help from the hosting company to implement something like NFS at the OS level.

If the domains will share a wordpress installation, what files remain to be hosted separately?

Comment: We need each account to have a seperate account so that we can control their emails, custom DNS records etc... via the control panel on an account by account basis.

Comment: Direct www.example.com to the root of your Wordpress instance, but files.example.com to the domain's own hosting.